# Need to create CLASS in my C# Console Application project

Tags: c#, class

This is my project (main.cs): http://pastebin.com/UhcZ3dtC
It´s C# Console Application created via Visual Studio and it is 100% working.

It is a school project, and my teacher has a problem with that, that all the code is in the main class and he wants me to create one more class, because he wants me to have in the new class all numerical operations. The main class should interact with the new class and take data from the new class.

I´m totally beginner in C# and I absolutely don´t know how to rework my project. I tried to work with some tutorials, but no result.

Can anyone help me and show me how to rework my project?

P.S. I'm not asking you for complete rework, but I'll be glad for showing me how to rework some part of my code.

Thanks

Comment: why would your teacher expect you to integrate basic language features that weren't covered in the course materials?

Comment: Are you asking how to type `public class SomeOtherClass { ... }` and then `var instance = new SomeOtherClass()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application with a simple multiply calculation.

An user implemented:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double multiplyScore = Convert.ToDouble(tBoxValue1.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(tBoxValue2.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not clean code, because you perform a calculation inside a button click.

To improve this code you can create a class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public double Multiply(double value1, double value2)
        {
            return value1 * value2;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this "Calculator" class and "Multiply" method, you need to create an instance of this Calculator class in  the Form:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Calculator calculator;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            calculator = new Calculator();
        }

        private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double multiplyScore = calculator.Multiply(Convert.ToDouble(tBoxValue1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(tBoxValue2.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can clean your code and implement a class with all numerical operations.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as creating another class and moving some methods to it. If you have no problems with basic C# syntax, then it is easy. Otherwise, I'd recommend grabbing a book about C# and reading it...

Also, starting with GUI programming should be done *after* getting to know the language and its most important standard library tools.